# how to capture timestamp of a stroke in canvas

Tags: wpf, timestamp, wpf-controls, stroke, inkcanvas

I am working with  thru InkManager trying to capture timestamp for each stroke.
Does anyone know how can I do it. The mmost inefficient way to make a list and update it each time a stroke been generated, but I am sure there is another efficient way to do it..

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? You should be able to hook into some event exposed in order to save the current timestamp when the stroke happens.

Comment: public void InkCanvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs capturedEvent)
        {

            if (capturedEvent.Pointer.PointerId == _penID)
            {
                _endPoint = capturedEvent.GetCurrentPoint(InkCanvas);
                // Pass the pointer information to the InkManager. 
                _inkManager.ProcessPointerUp(_endPoint);
            }

            else if (capturedEvent.Pointer.PointerId == _touchID)
            {
                // Process touch input
            }